# Bash <read> printing new lines, how to prevent

Tags: bash

So, I have a situation where I want to print output onto the output that was just posted by a user, and I wrote this short thing to make sure it's possible.

```
echo -e "Cmd> \c" && read cmd && echo "-append_something"
```

Although it would seem that read prints a new line, on "enter". Is there a way to cancel this? Or any other way I ***could*** print this output onto the same line.

Seeing input in real-time **IS** necessary.

Expected output: **`Cmd> <whatever>-append_something`**

Comment: Hm. `read cmd | tr -d '\n'` does _not_ do that. Interesting problem.

Comment: `read` shows what you type. When you hit `Enter`, it prints it.

Comment: Would `read -s cmd && echo -n $cmd` be acceptable? No instant feedback, though.

Comment: It's not `read` that prints a new line, but the user hitting Enter/Return to terminate the input, which is echoed back by the underlying terminal driver. You could turn that off (`stty -echo` or `read -s`), but then the rest of what is typed wouldn't be shown, either... Perhaps `stty -echonl` might be of use, but I haven't tried it...

Comment: @Boldewyn see edit, it is necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `-s` option to `read`:

```
echo -e "Cmd> \c" && read -s cmd && echo "-append_something"
```

Update:

Using classic ANSI screen cursor manipulation should do the trick:

```
echo -e "Cmd> \c"$'\e[s' && read cmd && echo $'\e[u'"${cmd}-append_something"
```

Simpler:

```
echo -ne "Cmd> \e[s" && read cmd && echo $'\e[u'"${cmd}-append_something"
```

Another shorter:

```
read -p "Cmd> "$'\e[s' cmd && echo $'\e[u'"${cmd}-append_something"
```

Something even more manual:

```
read -p "Cmd> " cmd && echo $'\e[A\e[5C'"${cmd}-append_something"
```

Comment: You need to echo `$cmd` back. See my comment above.

Comment: `echo -e "Cmd> \c"$'\e[s' && read cmd && echo $'\e[u\e[A'"${cmd}-append_something"`
 Cmd> sdasfa-append_something
`echo -e "Cmd> \c"$'\e[s' && read cmd && echo $'\e[u\e[A'"${cmd}-append_something"`
Cmd> sdasfa

It seems to only work on first occurance.

Comment: @RainbowDashDC Come again?

Comment: @konsolebox Apologies, I can not get formatting to work. Anyways, it only seems to work once, then it messes up the terminal screen, atleast in my case.

Comment: Hmm.. not sure how it causes a problem. It works well with me. I tried doing a loop: `while :; do read -p "Cmd> "$'\e[s' cmd && echo $'\e[u\e[A'"${cmd}-append_something"; done`. Output: `Cmd> a-append_something
Cmd> fdsafdas-append_something
Cmd> fasd-append_something
Cmd> fsaf-append_something
Cmd> asdfasfsadf-append_something
Cmd> 124234345-append_something
Cmd> 
`. Perhaps a problem with virtual terminal?

Comment: @konsolebox while this does work once, I need something that works for all terminals, even in just a bash script with a clear, it still only works once, so I cannot accept this :(

Comment: It appears removing "\e[A" fixed it.

Comment: @RainbowDashDC In my terminal it prints on the next line. Is that what you intended?

Comment: @konsolebox No, the same one.

Comment: I see. I guess you can't really fix that when terminals act differently.

Comment: Really cunning! +1 I found this CPAN reference of the ANSI codes for the curious reader: http://search.cpan.org/~jlmorel/Win32-Console-ANSI-1.08/lib/Win32/Console/ANSI.pm#Escape_sequences_for_Cursor_Movement

Comment: @RainbowDashDC Feel a little stupid here, but actually we can just calculate the number of steps to move up and move forward back to the original cursor position. Length of the prompt never changes anyway. See update.

Comment: @Boldewyn: Wikipedia has it too: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code. Another: http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences.php